# How can I filter which columns will be shown on a spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have filters set up for each column, however I also want to be able to filter which of the columns show. For example, I have 70 different columns, all with different headings. How can I create a filter that will only show the selected columns?

Each of my columns already has a drop-down filter to sort the data in the rows. I want to be able to do the same across the spreadsheet, from left to right, but only for the headings of each column.

Comment: You can manually hide the columns or use some VBA to automatically show/hide the columns but there is no horizontal *AutoFilter* (as mentioned previously by @techturtle in his/her answer.

Comment: *How* do you want to have the criteria for *which* column you want to see? The same way as the row filter, so based on the content of the single cells? Or based on the content of  the field headers?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a native way to do a horizontal version of the filter in Excel.

You could possibly achieve this functionality by means of pivot tables, but that would be highly dependent on how your data is arranged and what you need to see.  Your only other options would be a custom coded VBA routine, or to select each column and hide or unhide them as necessary.